# Spinner with save and cancel button in android

Tags: android, spinner

Hi I want to design a spinner with save and cancel button which looks like iphone drop down list.

Please suggest me with some example.

I tired searching it but could not find a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

Open “res/values/strings.xml” file, define the list of items that will display in Spinner (dropdown list).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<string name="spn_prompt">Choose one</string>
<resources>
    <string-array name="spn_arrays">
        <item>Save</item>
        <item>Cancel States</item>        
    </string-array>

</resources>
```

the set them inyour layout

```
 <Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinner1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/spn_arrays"
    android:prompt="@string/spn_prompt" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be create a custom `AlertDialog` with `Spinner` inside it. Here's an example for [Custom `AlertDialog`](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-custom-dialog-example/). When making apps for android I recommend following Android Design Guidelines instead of imitating iOS design because it will be confusing to users.